# How to assign file to istorage

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-8

How to assign file to istorage interface in c#?

I am new to c#. how to load file in istorage variable from program files folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an IsolatedStorgaeFile object and call CreateFile to create an IsolatedStorageFileStream.  You can then treat that pretty much exactly as you can a FileStream, so you can write to isolated storage in exactly the same way as you would a regular file.  You can call Write to write binary data directly to the file or you can put some other object on top of it, e.g. a StreamWriter, and use that to write text or transformed binary data.